# How to add protobuf in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, protobuf-net

I am trying to add protobuf to a ServiceStack based web project. But both the following approach gives errors

**Global.asax.cs**

```
 public AppHost() : base("My Service", typeof (HelloService).Assembly)
    {
       ServiceStack.Plugins.ProtoBuf.AppStart.Start();


    }
 public AppHost() : base("My Service", typeof (HelloService).Assembly)
    {

       Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat());

    }
```

How do I enable ProtoBuf format in the project?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention what errors you were getting, first ensure you've added the [ServiceStack ProtoBuf NuGet Package](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format).

Then adding the `ProtoBufFormat` plugin is all you need to do, but all configuration inc. registration of ServiceStack plugins must happen withing your `AppHost.Configure()` method, so try instead:

```
public class AppHost
{
   ...

   public void Configure(Container container)
   {
       Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat());
   }
}
```

Comment: I somehow figured it out by adding webactivator framework to the project, because the newer ServiceStack.Plugins.Protobuf removes it; I added it back by using an older ServiceStack.Plugins.Protobuf version @mythz

Comment: @jeff As it's 1-less dependency I prefer avoiding WebActivator myself, either way you just need to initialize ServiceStack on StartUp with `new AppHost().Init();`, either in Global.asax/Application_Start or using WebActivator.

Comment: I don't know why when I used the newest ServiceStack.Plugins.Protobuf the Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat()) or ServiceStack.Plugins.ProtoBuf.AppStart.Start() couldn't resolve dependencies.

Comment: @jeff   the Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat());   in AppHost.Configure,  not in the constructor.